# Spotify web scraping Beautifulsoup Shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code I have is too long to post here. What general scenarios would cause this AttributeError, what is NoneType supposed to mean and how can I fix this error?  I posted the code image for conviniences.

the part of the code before error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxmpC.png)

the next part where error occurs:

```
def get_countries():
    page = requests.get('https://spotifycharts.com/regional')
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
    countries = []
    ctys = soup.find('ul').findAll("li")
    for cty in ctys:
        countries.append([cty["data-value"],cty.get_text()])
    return(countries)

def scrape_data():
    countries = get_countries()
    for country in countries:
        save_data(country)

scrape_data()
```

This code returns error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'\

[error codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WwrP.png)

sorry i'm new to all this. i run this code just to get the dataset for my project. i have zero experience in web scraping

Comment: I suppose it happened cause `find('ul')` return None.

Comment: Next time do some basic research with the error message before posting. @koko is right `.find('ul')` return None. Even if you have never used, it's not difficult to do research on what's `NoneType` and the behavior of the `find()` method. From the doc of Beautiful Soup: `If find_all() can’t find anything, it returns an empty list. If find() can’t find anything, it returns None` [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

Answer (score 0):

Add `headers` to your code to get `content` from website now it will list data in `ctys`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"}
page = requests.get('https://spotifycharts.com/regional',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
countries = []
ctys = soup.find('ul').find_all("li")
```

How to find `headers`:

Go to website and then go to Network tab reload your website in which find website URL and click on `Headers` it will list out data in which find `user-agent` and you can use this in your code

Image:
[image]